# frequency domain vs cosine wave amplitude

Tags: frequency-spectrum, dft

[image]

Hey guys, what is the difference between b.) and c.)? Why do we need each of them?

Excrept from: http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/5.htm (scroll below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you cut off the explanation on the figure?

[image]

Equation 8-2:

[image]

Comment: k, it doesnt say what is the role of b and c in dft

Comment: What don't you understand about the text "Figure (b) shows the real part of the frequency domain of this signal" ?  What don't you understand about "Figure (c) shows the amplitudes of the cosine waves needed to construct (a) using Eq. 8-2" ? It's not clear what you're asking, or even why you're asking it given the clarity of the explanations of the source of your image.